# Do isomorphisms of quotients give isomorphisms of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have a group isomorphism $G/\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}^{(*n)}$, can I conclude from this fact
that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{(*(n+1))}$, the free product of (n+1) copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm not convinced that for $n+1\ge2$ that $\Bbb Z^{*(n+1)}$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

No, since perhaps $G$ is $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z^{(*n)}$.